# Why doesn't the T-800 run?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

I just re-watched the first two films in the *Terminator* series. The T1000 (Robert Patrick) does a lot of running, and is quite fast.

I didn't see many scenes where the T800 (Arnie) ran. Is it because he's really heavy? Is he mainly designed as a heavy "stand your ground" machine?

The only scene I could see him running is in T2 in the mental hostpital where the T1000 morphs through the metal gate and his gun gets caught. Then the T800 does a little jog to get into the elevator following John and Sarah. (anybody know of any other running/jogging scenes?) (EDIT Arnie also breaks into a run while pursuing Reece and Sarah down the alley after the *NOIR* nightclub attack.)

If he can at least jog though, why wouldn't he do this throughout the entire film? You would think that from a "chance of survival" point of view, if he could get a John even the slightest bit faster then he'd do so.

Of course, maybe I am overthinking this... Arnie walking around slowly is a lot more badass than Arnie jogging around.

Edit: Just watched T3 again, the T800 also ran towards the end when the big hangar door was closing and he ran over to slow it down. Interested in other examples of the T800 running too.

Comment: Power usage, presumably. Also the weight of the thing

Comment: @Richard doesn't he say that his power cell lasts about 120 years though? I don't know if this is how electricity works but it sounds to me he could at least get 60 years even if he was running everywhere :p

Comment: 100+ years in stand-by mode. Substantially less if he jogs everywhere, presumably.

Comment: @Richard what do you think about him only running when John is in immediate danger? or even in the first film when he'd have a better chance killing Sarah if he put a bit more effort into it

Comment: Slow-moving villains are inherently scary. One of the key selling points of the Terminator is that your death is inevitable. Why does he need to run fast if he's gonna kill you anyway?

Comment: @Richard is right, and I was going to comment that myself if he hadn't already done so. It's similar to the zombie trope; they may be slow moving, but they will never, ever, stop coming for you.

Comment: The T800 is an infiltrator unit, something of an assassin. As such, a priority in his programming might be more to be thorough rather than fast. Seek, identify, kill, rinse repeat. Works better slower, possibly. That said, he is seen to chase at least once, in a kind of loping jog. Consider how much he weighs, it might not be the friendliest on his system to do it too much. Or perhaps it has to be for short bursts to prevent damage to his batteries.

Comment: In T2 he is (almost) always protecting John Connor, so don't make much sense to outrun the person you are trying to protect. You need to keep their pace.

Comment: But, T-X is sexy. Isn't it? http://cdn.yourepeat.com/media/gif/000/240/501/71c70d17f2c37eb656c5c2edf2067e5e.gif

Comment: The T-800 begins to jog in the mall passageway after he picks up his gun. The T-1000 had just bested him in hand-to-hand combat and the T-800 needed to save John.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but at the start of the movies when you see the humans fighting the machines;  are the machine infantry all t 800s?  Their skeletons bare remarkable similarities. Remember John captures one and reprograms it.  Does this imply there was lots of them?  Does this justify the theory of the t800 foot soldiers?  What about the one that blasts it's way into a humans' shelter and starts shooting everyone?

Comment: Cool guys don't run. Or look back at explosions.

Comment: In the first film the T-800 breaks into a run when he chases Reece and Sarah down the ally after the attack at the nightclub soon after Reece says *Come with me if you want to live*.

Comment: I see a couple of reasons for this:  1:  In the second movie, he has to move slowly enough for John to keep up with him, and frequently has to use his own body as a shield to protect John.  2:  He wasn't built for speed, he was built for brute strength.

Comment: The T 800 is a classic exhaustion hunter.

Answer (score 15):

As others have already said, the T-800 *does* run occasionally, although he walks or jogs much more often.

As for why this is the case, I can offer a few possibilities, primarily based on the second movie.

**In-Universe**

- He doesn't move as fast as he is capable of, because he needs to stay close to John, and John isn't as fast as a Terminator.  In at least one or two scenes, he stays so close to John that he is able to use his own body as a shield to protect John from incoming fire.  Basically, he doesn't have to move as fast as possible, or even as fast as the T-1000 - he only needs to move as fast as John and Sarah move.  If he ran faster than them, he'd be tearing down the street while, far behind him, John and Sarah were being stabbed to death by the T-1000.
- Whatever his top speed is, he clearly wasn't built for speed - he was built for brute strength.  If he was supposed to be extremely fast, he wouldn't be so bulky.  If Skynet wanted him to be as fast as possible, he would probably look a lot more like the T-1000 - relatively thin and wiry, not an enormous bodybuilder with muscles on top of muscles.
- He doesn't need to run, or even jog, very often.  Most of the time, he is in a vehicle of some sort, or riding a motorcycle, both of which are faster than he could ever be (despite John's claim, while they are in the old pickup truck, that "I could get out and run faster than this!").
- As Praxis has pointed out, for most of T2, the T-800 (as well as John and Sarah) is not trying to catch up to the T-1000, he is trying to get away from it.  Since cars and motorcycles are much faster than a Terminator on foot, the point is somewhat moot.  While they are all on foot, the T-800 has to limit himself to John and Sarah's speed;  when they are in a vehicle, he can drive as fast as possible.

**Out-of-Universe**

- This is an example of a tried and true, standard operating procedure for movie villains (of course, in the second movie, the T-800 is a good guy, but he is, after all, a reprogrammed evil assassin robot):  For whatever reason, the killer is scarier if he moves slowly.  Jason Voorhees, for instance, never runs.  He never even walks quickly.  He just plods along at a leisurely pace.  This is also true of the first two Terminator movies - the T-800's rarely move faster than a quick walking pace.  Something about the sense of inexorable, inevitable doom that a slow moving killer provokes makes the killer that much more frightening - "This thing is so confident that it will murder me that it isn't even bothering to run after me!  It's just walking slowly towards me!"
- There are no scenes in T2 in which the T-800's slow pace puts it, or John and Sarah, at risk, because the scenes were written that way intentionally.  The writers didn't want the T-800 to move faster than it does on screen.

Comment: Very thorough --- I like.

Comment: @Praxis - I like your answer better.

Answer (score 8):

The T-800 *does* run in *The Terminator*.  For instance, he chases Sarah Connor and Kyle Reese down an alleyway after the nightclub incident, as @MajorStackings pointed out in the comments.

In-universe, I believe that the T-800s seen in *The Terminator* and *Terminator 2* do not run very often because:

- **the T-800 can drive a number of different human vehicles**
- **human vehicles are abundant in 1984 and 1991**

Why run when you can drive?  In *T2*, they are mostly trying to **escape** the T-1000 rather than engage it.  The T-1000 has a [top running speed](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Series_1000) of 40 miles/hour (64.3 km/hour).  The Harley Fat Boy that the T-800 rides in *Terminator 2* has a top speed of 130.5 miles/hour (210 km/hour).

(Without spoiling anything from *Genisys*, T-800s drive pick-up trucks to get around in 2029 too.)

Comment: Arnie also runs back to his bike when the couple flees the motel in a pick-up.

Answer (score 1):

If looking for a practical reason, the fact that he weighs (as we discover apparently in the latest movie) 400 pounds and running would be very hard on pavement.

Just as I type this I also think the flesh covering might be damaged (almost certainly would be) by running: the internal skeleton would easily tear the skin of the feet and ay serious damage would make the terminator's true nature evident.

Not sure the writers/director had this in mind but we actually see that the Terminator (perhaps) tries to be careful of its relatively fragile outer layer which, as in the very first movie, is memorable damaged (the eye scene which was very scary but one of the best in the series, imho.)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't addressed one way or another, but I think [Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum) has the right idea, it is for cinematic reasons.  Relentless, implacable, unstoppable doom is scary and if the hero has no chance to get away it makes for a very short movie.

Answer (score 0):

There is a scene in T2 in which the Terminator and John play "too slow". The Terminator is tricked by John to swipe empty air all the time because the T800 is... too slow.

so here my two cents:

- Hydraulics are inherently slow
- Forcing the system to run all the time requires a lot of power and shorten the battery life

Answer (score 0):

As noted before, the t-800 has moved at a jog (6-8mph) and possibly faster on more than one occasion. As for their hydraulics being slow, the opening scene of t2 shows the t800 grab a shotgun from a bar owner quicker than the bar owner could react. I bet he could hit johns hand if he tried but with enough force to fracture his wrist. Yes, the machine weighs quite a bit but it capable of producing so much force to counteract the weight. Also, the machine can't weight too much as it would bottom out the shocks on a motorcycle. Not be able to sit in a car with it being lopsided or overload a small elevator.

Answer (score 0):

The T-800 was not built to run or encounter heavy combat situations; it was meant to infiltrate the enemy camp and let loose destruction when the inmates of the camp are not prepared for a fight and are sleeping/resting and are recovering after battle. Hence, it was not designed to run frequently.

Answer (score -1):

I guess he doesn't run until he needs to. He does need to stay by whoever he's protecting and they're slower then him. According to the Wiki, the T-800 is capable of burst of speed of up to 22 mph.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please read the note in the yellow box below the question, and try adding some references/evidence.

Comment: "*Considering its options, it decided to commandeer the truck to continue the pursuit. As it started forward, its internal screen displayed damage reports. Backups started kicking into the battered hydraulics, but nothing could be done about the pivot joint in the left ankle. It was main-frame damage that would require full attention later, if necessary. But actually all it did was cause the machine to limp. And it could no longer sprint up to twenty-two miles an hour. But it could walk."* - Terminator Novelisation