# Why can terminators (T-8XX) only run when they have flesh on their endoskeletons?

Tags: the-terminator-series

Never really got the reason, it seems that when they only have their endoskeletons they are super sluggish and can only walk... I don't see how putting flesh on that would actually help.

When did it happen:
Well when Pops (in Salvation) shoots the other supposedly T-800 the one who came asking the clothes of the junkies and then started running towards Pops.

Comment: When does a T-800 ever run?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94614/20774

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I edited my question and give an example.

Comment: My question is more specific. And they do run a few times.

Comment: You'd be sluggish too if you only had your endoskeleton.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of possibilities. For starters, without a boot, their feet are small hard surfaces without any traction, so they may skid easily on hard surfaces and sink into the ground if it is soft.

[image]

So they walk slowly to maintain their balance and mobility.

Second, you rarely see an undamaged de-fleshed T-800. At the end of T1 it has been substantially damaged, the semi-defleshed one in T:S (that a young Reese fights) looks to be in bad shape as well. The intact ones in the beginning of T2 are not in a hurry and are crossing very uneven unstable ruins, so with those pointy little feet they would have to move slowly. They are also carrying big ass guns, which may prevent them from running easily.

Comment: The liquid metal one ran after the car, remember?